# Not displaying bullets in ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I a have a problem with displaying bullets in ul.

Does anyone know where the problem is?
[my site](http://www.minikoblizky.wz.cz/zamestnanci.html) and it starts with Co od vás očekáváme

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `<li>` tags have the `display: block` CSS rule that is overriding the default behaviour. The `<li>` elements have `display: list-item` to been displayed as default, with bullets. You can make something like this (based on your HTML structure):

```
 section ul li { 
     display: list-item;
 }
```

And it works automaticaly (only inside `<section> <ul>` places).

Answer (score 1):

You have used the default styling of ul in your site. 
What you can do is you can add a separate class to ul element, for eg bullets like this :-

CSS :-

```
.bullets {
}

.bullets li {
 list-style-type: circle;
}
```

HTML :-

```
<ul class="bullets">
 <li>dobrý zdravotní stav bez omezení, potravinářský průkaz</li>
 <li>manuální zručnost v kuchyni – rychlost, přesnost, šikovnost a      pečlivost – bez toho to nejde</li>
 <li>samostatnost a zodpovědnost</li>
 <li>radost z prodeje</li>
 <li>aktivní komunikaci se zákazníkem.</li>
</ul>
```