# HTML Bullets Not Showing

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am using the TinyMCE gem with Rails (if that even matters) to generate text on my site.  All the sudden bullet points are not appearing.  (They used to display just fine.)

After all the ERB is rendered, the final HTML is pretty unstyled and boring (it looks like this...)

```
<ul>
   <li>Text here</li>
   <li>More text here</li>
</ul>
```

There is no CSS that speaks directly to bullets (ul, li, or ol).

Looking at other  StackOverflow posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717804/not-displaying-bullets-in-ul)) you're supposed to ensure that `<li>` tags have the css property `display: list-item`, but when I look at them in the Chrome inspector, they do have this display property.

You can see the issue live [here](https://www.sixkeyskills.com/blogs/how-to-stop-procrastinating#h_7692833417921592859851807) if you want to verify that this property is correct.

Other than this, I'm not sure what could be causing the issue.  What else can I check for?  I've never had bullets just disappear before!

Comment: Where exactly in your example is the issue occuring?

Comment: I can see bullets on your page with iphone safari if I click on reader view https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.imore.com/how-use-reader-view-safari-iphone-and-ipad%3famp so it’s styling or overlaying issue.

Comment: @Spectric That's what I'm trying to find out.  The bullets just aren't appearing.  I've tested it in Chrome, Safari, even IE.

Comment: @Liz I'm asking you where the bullets are supposed to be, since I can't find them.

Comment: They're supposed to be to the left of each of the bolded terms under the heading "Individual Characteristics". @Spectric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your live issue [here](https://www.sixkeyskills.com/blogs/how-to-stop-procrastinating#h_7692833417921592859851807)

`overflow-x: hidden;` on `<li>`

is hiding the bullets.

Removing it or adding
`overflow-x : unset;` may help

Comment: Yes!  This works.  But why!?!  I don't understand what the two have to do with each other?

Comment: @Liz may be because of default behaviour of `list-style-position` which is `outside`